# Overflow for inline columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I'm working on a display for my homepage. I created five col-md-2's within a container, and resized the columns to the width that I need. Resizing them was easy, but now I've ran into an issue. Rather than these columns all equaling out to take up 83.3% of the total container width, after resizing them they now take up a total of ~116% of the container. Some of these columns are margined to overlap each other a little bit, but there will still be some extra space that needs to overflow the container on both the left side and right side. I can get the far left column to overflow outside of the container, but I'm having a hard time getting the far right column to overflow. Any time the far right (blue) div is too big to fit in the inline space, its pushed down. Does anyone know how I can force the blue div to overflow the right side of the container, rather than it being pushed down? I've tried to use the overflow property, but haven't had any luck =. I'd like to have the overflow on the left and right set to hidden, but any overflow will work for the time being!

HTML:

```
<div class="date-con">
    <div class="col-md-2 green">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 white-left">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 red">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 white-right">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 blue">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.date-con {
    width: 75%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightpink;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.date-con .green {
    width: 24.5%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: -1.5%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    display: inline-block;
}
.date-con .white-left {
    width: 19.83333333333333%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    margin-left: -3.1%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
z-index: 10;
}
.date-con .red {
    width: 23.66666666666667%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: -3.1%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 100;
}
.date-con .white-right {
    width: 23%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    margin-left: -3.6%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}
.date-con .blue {
    width: 25.41666666666667%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: -3.5%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Here is my bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/117408

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat unclear what you're trying to achieve - an image of the desired end result would help.

But in order to allow `.blue` to stay inline you need to apply a negative `margin-right` to compensate for the width overflow. Depending on how fluid/responsive your design needs to be I found a minimum value of -1.999% works on a wide screen, but you can easily set it lower.

And then you can apply `overflow: hidden` to the `.date-con` element to clip the entire area, if that's what you're after.

Plus - watch out for whitespace width and subpixel width rounding affecting your end result on different screens/browsers/OSs.